# Which distance sensor to lock screen if I leave my seat?

Tags: hardware, screen-lock

This is follow-up to this question: [Automatically lock screen if I leave the MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376729/automatically-lock-screen-if-i-leave-the-macbook)

I want to get some signal from a sensor if I leave the seat.

Background: I change the job and in the new company you need to pay pizza for the whole team if you forget to lock your screen :-)

I want it to be automated: I walk away and the screen should lock. No additional action should be required. Keyboard shortcuts, special mouse movements or unplugging devices from USB are not valid answers.

I never worked with sensors before.

Which sensor could be used to detect that I left my seat?

Comment: A cushion on your chair maybe? :-) Or an application using the camera to detect whether somebody sits in front of it.

Comment: @nohillside where can I buy a cushion which sends a digital signal?

Comment: Sounds like a job for an Arduino, a pressure sensor and some DIY work :-) https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ might help.

Comment: @ankii - Are you suggesting there are adverse health effects to using an infrared detector? Or even an emitter, part of the natural spectrum of sunlight, and powered typically at 20mW? Citation needed.

Comment: I guess I am mistaken, due to a very old poorly informed reading which I never felt the need to revisit. @GlenYates thanks for reminding me to read some more over it

Answer (score 1):

> Which sensor could be used to detect that I left my seat?

There is no sensor in any Mac that can be used to detect if you left your seat.

Rhetorically speaking, how would this hypothetical sensor work?  How would it differentiate between not being in your seat because you left and not being in your seat because you have a standing desk?

The answer is it can’t.

The closest you can get to automating the locking/unlocking of your based on your physical position is through proximity.  There’s an app called [Near Lock](https://nearlock.me/) that purports to achieve this, however, it requires an iPhone; it’s implied that you use an Android as you mention a Huawai smartwatch in your linked question.

Further, you’re looking to automate something that *by design* should be a user interactive process.  As someone responsible for security and IT governance in my organizations, I can clearly see why they have the policy they do.  They are trying to develop security minded habits.

Comment: "...that by design should be a user interactive process." - Not sure what is more user interactive, than getting up and walking away!